# postgresql ram setting for 16gb macbook

Tags: postgresql, ram, sysctl

I'm in the development stage of an application and happened that I have to use Postgresql. In the README file are the following instructions...

```
On a MacBook Pro with 2GB of RAM, the author's sysctl.conf contains:

    kern.sysv.shmmax=1610612736
    kern.sysv.shmall=393216
    kern.sysv.shmmin=1
    kern.sysv.shmmni=32
    kern.sysv.shmseg=8
    kern.maxprocperuid=512
    kern.maxproc=2048

Note that (kern.sysv.shmall * 4096) should be greater than or equal to
kern.sysv.shmmax. kern.sysv.shmmax must also be a multiple of 4096.
```

I'm guessing that for development I wouldn't have problem leaving the default setting for my Mac, however, there are occasions where I'm running some python script to do data science and I would like to take advantage all the resources available (RAM). What would be the correct configuration for 16GB of RAM.

Comment: if you solved this, can you share solution with us? I've same doubt about how adjust the kernel params for the postgresql.

Comment: Sadly I have not.